# Recursive component view does not display after data change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, treeview

A common need for data binding is manipulating an element's class list and inline styles. Since class and style are both attributes, we can use v-bind to assign them a string value dynamically, much like with other attributes.

I want to have 2d array with turned on and off dates checked in component by v-if

interesting variable is dir.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
      <h4>
        Vue.js Expandable Tree Menu<br />
        <small>(Recursive Components)</small>
      </h4>
      <div id="app">
        <tree-menu :nodes="tree.nodes" :depth="0" :label="tree.label" :dir="dir"></tree-menu>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      let tree = {
        label: "root",
        nodes: [
          {
            label: "item1",
            nodes: [
              {
                label: "item1.1",
              },
              {
                label: "item1.2",
                nodes: [
                  {
                    label: "item1.2.1",
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            label: "item2",
          },
        ],
      };

      Vue.component("tree-menu", {
        props: ["nodes", "label", "depth", "dir"],
        template: `
    <div >
    <div class="label-wrapper" @click="toggleChildren">
      <div :style="indent" :class="labelClasses">
        <i v-if="nodes" class="fa" :class="iconClasses"></i>
        {{ label }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <tree-menu
      v-if="dir[0][0]"
      v-for="node in nodes"
      :nodes="node.nodes"
      :label="node.label"
      :depth="depth + 1"
      :dir="dir"
    >
    </tree-menu>
  </div>`,

        data() {
          return {
            showChildren: false,
          };
        },
        computed: {
          iconClasses() {
            return {
              "fa-plus-square-o": !this.showChildren,
              "fa-minus-square-o": this.showChildren,
            };
          },
          labelClasses() {
            return { "has-children": this.nodes };
          },
          indent() {
            return { transform: `translate(${this.depth * 50}px)` };
          },
        },
        methods: {
          toggleChildren() {
            this.dir[0][0] = !this.dir[0][0];
            alert(this.dir[0][0]);
          },
        },
      });

      new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
          tree,
          dir: [
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          ],
        },
      });
    </script>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: 1em;
      }

      .container {
        width: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .tree-menu {
        .label-wrapper {
          padding-bottom: 10px;
          margin-bottom: 10px;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
          .has-children {
            cursor: pointer;
          }
        }
      }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to have 2d array with turned on and off dates that are checked by `v-if`.

Comment: Hi, welcome here. Please put more effort into your question next time (at least some basic decent formatting).

Comment: hello, sorry for that, its because of my English